# Akka Http return different type of response based on Accept header

Tags: scala, akka, spray, akka-http

I'm novice to scala and Akka-Http. Experimenting Akka-Http for writing rest services. I have to return json or protobuf based on the `Accept` header.

```
 optionalHeaderValueByName("Accept"){ contentType =>
  if(contentType == Some(protoEncode)) {
    complete {
      NewsService.getNewsList().map {
        case stories: List[Story] =>    HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(ContentType(protoEncoding),  StoryList(stories).toProto().build().toByteArray))
      }
    }
  } else {
      complete {
        NewsService.getNewsList().map {
          case stories: List[Story] => StoryList(stories)
          }
        }
  }
```

As you can see the code repetition is happening can anyone suggest what could be the best way to optimise and generalise design to avoid such situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
optionalHeaderValueByName("Accept") { contentType =>
   onSuccess(NewsService.getNewsList()) {
       case stories: List[Story] => contentType match {
           case Some(protoEncodingString) => complete(HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(ContentType(protoEncoding),  StoryList(stories).toProto().build().toByteArray)))
           case  _=> complete(StoryList(stories))

         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to move the check inside the body.

```
optionalHeaderValueByName("Accept"){ contentType =>
      complete {
        NewsService.getNewsList().map {
          case stories: List[Story] =>
            if(contentType == Some(protoEncode)) {
              HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(ContentType(protoEncoding),  StoryList(stories).toProto().build().toByteArray))
            } else
              StoryList(stories)
        }  
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. the way you suggested would work generally. But, akka-http complete method doesn't accept two different return types. I've updated the code please check it out.

Comment: @user3487990 You should post that as an answer rather than editing it into the question